# Jackson Mapping with object in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Java POJO where I have declared certain fields. One of the fields is:

```
private Page<MyAbcClass> pageDto;
```

The Page object is org.springframework.data.domain.Page

When I send this object from my UI that is built upon angular, the object could not map correctly and throws this exception:

```
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.data.domain.Page, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2a89f0ab; line: 1, column: 9233] (through reference chain: com.abc.JavaPojo["pageDto"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:892)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:139)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:339)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2810)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:222)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

There is some probelm with the JSON mapping but I could not figure what.

Comment: Have you tried with postman. whether the service is working or not?

Comment: I will just do it and update with the result. Thnx

Comment: Hi @PraneethReddy It did not work through Postman too. It only maps the request correctly when I send the object as null.